# Deploying Machine Learning model to AzureML Web Service - how to deal with extreme high dimensionality?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, azure-machine-learning-service

I want to deploy a Sklearn knn model onto Azure ML Web Service according the following tutorial.

```
from azureml import services
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier

knn_model = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=5, n_jobs=-1, algorithm="auto")
knn_model.fit(X_train, Y_train)

@services.publish(workspace_id, authorization_token)
@services.types(input_1=int, input_2=int, input_3=int, input_4=int)
@services.returns(int)
def my_knn_predictor(input_1, input_2, input_3, input_4):
    return knn_model.predict([input_1, input_2, input_3, input_4])
```

This works indeed, but in the meantime I have to deploy a model where both the input and output dimensionality is very high (magnitude of thousands) so I do not want to type in the `input_1, input_2, input_3, input_4 ...` variable sequences by hand. Is there a way to extract these as a list from the `X_train` and `Y_train` and feed this list into the `my_knn_predictor` input/output definition? (Simple copy of the data frame headers is not enough because I have to add `=int` to the column names and remove the quotation marks.)

Comment: How do you get input_1, input_2, etc. ? Are they columns in X_train?

Comment: Yes. The predictor columns must be enumerated one by one by hand with the type definitions at @service.types().